# Movement system and dash not working together - unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I have been trying to learn to use unity, and the most difficult part for me is learning programing. I'm trying to create a simple 2d top-down game. I have a solid movement system for my character, and a not so solid dash. But the thing is, those 2 things don't want to work together. My character can walk around with the full code active, but not dash. If I remove the line that warrants the possition change the dash magically starts working.

I'm gonna paste my code here:

```
public class Player_movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float DashSpeed;
    private float DashTime;
    public float startDashTime;
    private int direction;
    Vector2 movement;

    void Start()
    {rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    DashTime = startDashTime;   
    }

    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if(direction == 0)
        {
            
         if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
            direction = 1;
        }else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
            direction = 2;
        }else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
            direction = 3;
        }else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
            direction = 4;
        }
            
        }
            else 
            {
                if(DashTime <= 0){
                direction = 0;
                DashTime = startDashTime;
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;}

                else
                {
                    DashTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                    {
                    
                    if(direction == 1){
                        rb.velocity = Vector2.left * DashSpeed;
                    }else if(direction == 2){
                        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * DashSpeed;
                    }else if(direction == 3){
                        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * DashSpeed;
                    }else if(direction == 4){
                        rb.velocity = Vector2.down * DashSpeed;
                    }

                    }
                    
                }    
            }  
        }

void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

As i said, if I remove rb.MovePosition, the dash starts working. I tried to change rb.MovePosition to rb.velocity, but the dash still won't work. I tried to swap every single component of that last line, but nothing worked.
I'm really out of ideas, can someone advise me what am I doing wrong, or why this is not compatible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Calling MovePosition on a rigidbody is like an override that **forces** the rigidbody to be interpolated to the position you give it. Because of this, the rigidbody will not respond to other motions such as your dash code, which is using velocity.

An easy way around this would be to set a bool while you are dashing like

```
isDashing = true;
```

And then in your fixed update you can do your move position only if you are not dashing such as

```
if (!isDashing) {
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

This way, you're using your velocity based movement while dashing, and your MovePosition based movement while not dashing.

Just remember to set your isDashing variable to false when the dash ends, so that control passes back to your movement code.